# How to return an object with HTML or XML MIME types in Jersey?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey

I have the following Jersey method to wrap the HTTP headers in a Java `Set<String>` object.

```
@GET
@Path("header-info")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Response getAllHeaders() {
    Map<String, List<String>> headerMap = headers.getRequestHeaders();
    Set<String> headerNames = headerMap.keySet();
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String header : headerNames){
        String headerValue = headerMap.get(header).get(0);
        values.add(headerValue);
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(values).build();
}
```

I want to return the set of strings in XML or HTML MIME types. But when I access the link, I get the error

```
A message body writer for Java class java.util.HashSet, and Java type class java.util.HashSet, and MIME media type text/xml was not found
```

I guess it is because the object returned in the Response `Set<String> values` does not have a message body writer for XML. The same error happens if I use HTML MIME type:

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
```

I notice that there is a [MessageBodyWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) interface in Jersey that can write any object to XML. But I need to implement this interface to write to XML. Also I need to implement it again to write to HTML. Is there a quick and easy way to directly serialize Java object to XML and HTML in Jersey?

Comment: that's because your marshaller can't map Set<String>, try to return String[], i faced this kind of problems with jackson library

Comment: @EugenHalca I tried it with returning String[] but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to update your response content type annotation to:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
```

Then you'll need to annotate your entity with JAXB so that Jersey knows how to marshall it into XML. Try to create a JAXB-annotated wrapper, e.g.:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="set")
public class JaxbSet<T> implements Set<T> {
    protected Set<T> set;
    public JaxbSet(Set<T> set){
        this.set=set;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public Set<T> getSet(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

then pass this wrapper as your response entity:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(new JaxbSet<String>(values)).build();
```